# How to find complex roots of $x^7-1=0$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, factoring

I'm struggling to figure out how to find the roots of this question.
If $w$ is a complex root of the equation: $$x^7-1=0$$ show that $w^2,w^3,w^4,w^5, w^6$ are the other complex roots.

I know that you can factorise it into:
$$(x-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=0$$

But I don't know where to go from there.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if $w^7=1$ then $(w^2)^7=w^{14}=(w^7)^2=1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I assume you mean $w^{14}$ there? Ah never mind, you edited it :)

Comment: Divide the second factor by $x^3$ (x=0 can be seen that is not a root) and write it as a function of $y=x+1/x$. It results in a cubic on $y$. You can solve the cubic and the for each root $y$ solve for $x$ in the quadratic equation $x^2-yx+1=0$. This gives you the solutions written in radicals.

Comment: If you can leave the solutions in terms of trigonometric functions, then it is enough to use DeMoivre $(e^{it})^7=e^{7it}$. Since $w^7=1$ implies that $|w|=1$, then $w=e^{it}$ for some $t$. From $e^{7it}=1=e^{2\pi i}$ you can find one solution $t=2\pi/7$. So, $w=e^{2\pi i/7}=\cos(2\pi/7)+i\sin(2\pi/7)$.

Comment: If you want them expressed as operations with a compass and a marked rule, then you can [do this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagon#Construction).

Comment: @conditionalMethod Can you explain how you would write this as a function of $y=x+1/x$ when that equation has two roots? How would you know which root to use?

Comment: @Math1000 Which equation you think has two roots? How is that a problem? Why do you need to know which root to use? Why do you need to use one root and not the other? What is it what you really don't know?

Comment: @conditionalMethod thanks for your answer earlier about using DeMoivre's Theorem, it got me the answer!

Comment: @conditionalMethod To do this we need to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ and substitute in those expressions of $y$ for $x$, correct? Or am I off-base here?

Comment: @Math1000 The rational functions $x^m+x^{-m}$ can be expressed as polynomials in $x+x^{-1}$. Apply induction observing that $x^m+x^{-m}-(x+x^{-1})^m$ is a linear combination of rational functions like the one before but with smaller powers. Now, the second factor in the question, divided by $x^3$ is $x^3+x^{-3}+x^2+x^{-2}+x+x^{-1}+1$. Do that and you get a cubic on $x+x^{-1}$.

Comment: That is very brilliant but I'm afraid it didn't follow from your original comment. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Math1000 "It" didn't follow, or "you" didn't follow?

Comment: It didn't follow for me. Perhaps it would for someone with more experience with these sorts of algebraic manipulations :)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Your hint would be immediately clear if you'd used a different variable from $w.$

Comment: Always ask the question first before showing what you've done. You don't really need to find these roots (whatever this may mean) to prove that they satisfy the given equation.

Answer (score 3):

Let $w$ be a complex root of $x^7-1=0$.  Then $w^7=1$ and $w\ne1$.

Now $w^n$ is also a root of $x^7-1=0$ because $(w^n)^7=w^{7n}=(w^7)^n=1^n=1.$

Furthermore, if $n$ is relatively prime to $7$ then $w^n\ne1$, or else we would have $w=1$,

and that would contradict the assumption that $w$ is complex.

Comment: What? $x^7-1=0$ has $6$ complex roots, unless both I and Mathematica are wrong.

Comment: It does have $6$ complex roots:  $w$, $w^2$, $w^3$, $w^4$, $w^5$, and $w^6$

Comment: Perhaps I should have said $w^n=w^m$ iff $n\equiv m \pmod 7$

Comment: Oh, I did not read your proof closely enough. You began with "Let $w$ be a complex root..." and concluded with "...would contradict the assumption that $w$ was complex. So I took it as proving that the equation having no complex roots. My confusion.

Comment: The question stated that $w$ is a complex root and that there are 6 more complex roots. I'm just a bit confused by your answer. Could you please clarify your answer?

Comment: The roots are in the form $1$, $\omega$, $\omega^2$, $\ldots$, $\omega^6$.

Comment: The question says $w$ is a complex root and so are $w^2$, $w^3$, $w^4$, $w^5$, and $w^6$ (i.e., there are $5$ complex roots besides $w$, for a total of $6$ complex roots); that makes sense because $x^7-1$ has $7$ roots and one of them is $1$